# is it possible to save offline map in pdf file

Tags: google-maps, pdf

I used Google map and visited a location and saved it as an html page by this I am able to view that location in future also with zoom functionality. Is it possible to save that location(map) in .pdf format instead of html format with zooming capability.
If yes how and if no then please answer why.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to print that html file, the print dialog will pop up with the default printer. Click 'change' under the printer and choose 'Save as PDF'. You can zoom a pdf in adobe reader.

or (the long way)

Launch InDesign and create a new A4 landscape document. Now press F (Frame tool) on your keyboard and drag a frame with a size you wish to have for the map.

Go to Workspace settings (top right corner of InDesign) and change it to interactive for PDF. Go to Window → Interactive → Buttons. In InDesign you can create buttons very easily. Create any object and then right click and select Interactive - Convert to button.

To import a Google map to flash you need to download Google Map Component - map_1_18.swc.

In Windows 7 navigate to C:Program Files (x86)AdobeAdobe Flash CS6CommonConfigurationComponents. Then create a new folder there and name it Google. Store the .swc file there and then go to this page and follow the instruction to get the API key and save it. Your Flash is now set up to supports Google maps API.

Open the Components panel by pressing CTRL + F7 or click Window  →  Components in the menu. You should see the Google map library there. Drag and drop it to the Library panel.

Go to Layer panel in timeline and call it e.g. gmap. Open the Action panel (or Press F9) Windows → Actions. Now put there the code below to import the map:

```
import com.google.maps.LatLng;
import com.google.maps.Map;
import com.google.maps.Map3D;
import com.google.maps.MapEvent;
import com.google.maps.MapType;
import com.google.maps.View;
import com.google.maps.geom.Attitude;
```

// Creating map variable

```
var map:Map3D;


/ Creating map
 create_map();
 function create_map()
 {
 map = new Map3D();
 map.key = "your api key";
 map.setSize(new Point(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight));
 map.addEventListener(MapEvent.MAP_READY, onMapReady);
 this.addChild(map);
 }
 function onMapReady(event:MapEvent):void
 {
 map.setCenter(new LatLng(48.207401,16.372805), 13);
 map.setAttitude(new Attitude(20,30,0));
 map.viewMode = View.VIEWMODE_PERSPECTIVE;
 }
```

In order to create the marker, you need to put some ActionScript again. Go to ActionScript panel and copy the following code. Change the classes to match yours if necessary.

```
var c:Marker = new Marker(new LatLng(-33.925272,18.423557),
new MarkerOptions({icon:new capeTown()}));
map.addOverlay(c);
var p:Marker = new Marker(new LatLng(50.075651,14.431229),
new MarkerOptions({icon:new prague()}));
map.addOverlay(p);
var v:Marker = new Marker(new LatLng(48.206371,16.375122),
new MarkerOptions({icon:new vienna()}));
map.addOverlay(v);}
```

If you want to have control fly.to animations with acrobat buttons. Since we call ActionScript from Javascript, we use the function ExternalInterface.addCallback that will build bridge between SWF and Acrobat Javascript. Create a new action layer and put there something similar to this. It should have the same marker coordinates:

```
function pr(e:MouseEvent = null):void
{
map.flyTo(new LatLng(50.075651,14.431229),12,new Attitude(0,0,4),5);
 }
ExternalInterface.addCallback("pr",pr);
function vn(e:MouseEvent = null):void
{
map.flyTo(new LatLng(48.206371,16.375122),9,new Attitude(0,30,3),5);
}
ExternalInterface.addCallback("vn",vn)
function cp(e:MouseEvent = null):void
{
map.flyTo(new LatLng(-33.925272,18.423557),3,new Attitude(0,30,-10),3);
}
ExternalInterface.addCallback("cp",cp)
```

With map.flyTo function you can control the following parameters: LatLng, Zoom, Attitude, Time.

Now open your InDesign file again, that we have already prepared. Select the frame that will serve as placeholder for the map. With placeholder selected press CTRL + D (File – Import) to place your SWF map. Open the media panel and check Play on Page Load on. Choose None for Poster option. Now you are ready to export it to interactive PDF. Go to File – Export or CTRL + E and select Adobe PDF Interactive.

Open the file in Acrobat. You have your interactive Acrobat buttons and your embedded Google map there. The buttons do nothing now, except for the rollover effect if you have created any. In the Interactive tab tools choose select object tool and double click on one of the buttons. In the windows that arrive go to Actions and from Select action dropdown menu select Run a Javascript, Then Press Add. In a a new windows that open again put the following code:

```
getAnnotsRichMedia(this.pageNum)[0].callAS(“pr”);
```

Press OK and close

[Reference](http://designus.sk/animated-google-maps-in-pdf/)

Comment: in that case if I try to zoom the map it doesn't work like that html file. Shall I move to .swf file instead of .pdf?

Comment: Visit this link http://www.dsclsugar.com/plot-by-id/frm_map.aspx?id1=%272887553%27&id2=%27%27&id3=%27%27&id4=%27%27&id5=%27%27&id6=%27%27&lat=27.678206&lng=80.201646
you will see a yellow marker there. at that point I am plotting a polygon save it in html and pdf both formats then check zoom functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at the Static Maps API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/. It allows you to request 640x640 Static Maps and you can adjust the zoom accordingly by altering the parameter. You can either use coordinates or names of places, which will get geocoded for your request.

Here are a few examples with different zoom levels and map types:

640x640, Zoom 14, Terrain Map:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Eiffel+Tower&zoom=14&size=640x640

640x640, Zoom 18, Satellite: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Eiffel+Tower&zoom=18&size=640x640&maptype=satellite

Be aware though that according to 10.1.2.(b) of the [Terms of Use](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms), you:

- (b) No Direct Marketing.  You must not print more than 5,000 copies of sales collateral
  materials containing a screenshot of the Content for purposes of
  commercial sales lead generation ("Direct Marketing") or incorporate
  the Content as a core part of printed matter (such as printed maps or
  guide books) that you redistribute for a fee. You must contact the
  Google Maps API for Business sales team to obtain a direct license if
  you desire to do either of the above.